# JTabbedPane's tab area add a button, it can display, but it can't click

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a `JTabbedPane` with tabs on the top. To the right of the tabs, I add a button. This button is neither part of `JTabbedPane` nor is it a tab. Unfortunately, it cannot be clicked. I guess this button is covered by the `JTabbedPane`, because I moved the button down, it covered by the `JTabbedPane`.

Can anybody give me some suggestion, so that I can click that button?

This is the layout; I can't upload image, so I draw it like below:

```
|-------------------------------------|
|   tab   |  tab   |           button |
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|               content               |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

Comment: no issues on my side, works as excepts, please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: To make a button can be clicked, you must make sure this button is inside swing tree, not just draw it in the screen.

I guess what happens for you is that you did not set the parent component for the button, or just put the button in the paint() ?

Comment: Why add buttons to the tab of a tabbed pane?  What do they do?

Comment: I find the answer, I first add button to the contetPane,the add the JTabledPane to the contenPane, then it can click.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but you may be able to leverage one of approaches adduced by @camickr in the article [*Component Border*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/). A custom `TabbedPaneUI` is a (laborious) alternative.