# Button size settled as mini

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtabbedpane

Based on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html with the purpose to create a button that fits one tab from JTabbedPane [How to add close button to a JTabbedPane Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553112/how-to-add-close-button-to-a-jtabbedpane-tab) I built the code below. It should show a mini button as is in java documentation, but even that I change the size the results are the same. What am I doing wrong please? Thanks in advance

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class buttontest {

public static void main (String[] args){

        buttontest t = new buttontest();

    }

public buttontest(){
    JFrame test = new JFrame();
    JPanel pnlTab = new JPanel();
    JButton btnClose = new JButton("x");
    btnClose.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "mini");

    pnlTab.add(btnClose);
    test.add(pnlTab);
    test.setVisible(true);
            }
}
```

**EDIT ONE:**

```
try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

Comment: You can only use that property with LAF's that support that property. Nimbus LAF supports that property.

Comment: See also [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg).

Comment: @camickr which can be called on the code using the edit one update, but I didnt see any big difference, is that really usefull?

Comment: @trashgod I already toke a look on it but was really quick, I will take another time - thanks; Do you guys have any other Idea of what I could do? http://tips4java.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/component-border.jpg I would like something like this "x" button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like something like this "x" button

You can use the actual Icon from that image.

In the `ButtonTabComponent` class from the demo code, you can add the following statement to the constructor of the `TabButton` private class:

```
setIcon( UIManager.getIcon("InternalFrame.closeIcon") );
```

Then comment out the paintComponent() code of the class and the Icon will be painted as the close button.

Comment: I will checkout later cos I'm already tired of programm; But I would like to ask, since this work like a paintComponent() it will be painted as pixel size of the icon or like a default size from the button component? thank you for the support, soon as possible I will check as correct answer if it applys