# Closeable JTabbedPane - alignment of the close button

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have implemented my own closeable `JTabbedPane` (essentially following advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553112/how-to-add-close-button-to-a-jtabbedpane-tab) - by extending `JTabbedPane` and overriding some methods and calling setTabComponentAt(...)). It works perfectly except one thing - when there are too many tabs to fit on one row (when there are 2 or more rows of tabs), the cross button/icon is not aligned to the right of the tab but it remains next to the tab title, which looks ugly. I've tried the demo from Java tutorials and it suffers from the same problem.

What I want is that the cross button/icon is always aligned to the very right, but the text is always aligned to the center. Can this be achieved by some layouting tricks? Note: I do not want to implement a custom `TabbedPaneUI` as this leads to other problems.

**UPDATE** I'm forced to use Java 6

The complete code is below, just run it and add 5 or more tabs.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;


/**
 * CloseableTabbedPane is a tabbed pane with a close icon on the right side of all tabs making it possible to close a tab.
 * You can pass an instance of TabClosingListener to one of the constructors to react to tab closing.
 * 
 * @author WiR
 */
public class CloseableTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

    public static interface TabClosingListener {
        /**
         * @param aTabIndex the index of the tab that is about to be closed
         * @return true if the tab can be really closed
         */
        public boolean tabClosing(int aTabIndex);

        /**
         * @param aTabIndex the index of the tab that is about to be closed
         * @return true if the tab should be selected before closing
         */
        public boolean selectTabBeforeClosing(int aTabIndex);
    }

    private TabClosingListener tabClosingListener;
    private String iconFileName = "images/cross.gif";
    private String selectedIconFileName = "images/cross_selected.gif";

    private static Icon CLOSING_ICON;
    private static Icon CLOSING_ICON_SELECTED;

    private class PaintedCrossIcon implements Icon {

        int size = 10;

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + size, y + size);
            g.drawLine(x + size, y, x, y + size);
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return size;
        }

    }

    public CloseableTabbedPane() {
        super();
    }

    public CloseableTabbedPane(TabClosingListener aTabClosingListener) {
        super();
        tabClosingListener = aTabClosingListener;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file name of the closing icon along with the optional variant of the icon when the mouse is over the icon.
     */
    public void setClosingIconFileName(String aIconFileName, String aSelectedIconFileName) {
        iconFileName = aIconFileName;
        selectedIconFileName = aSelectedIconFileName;
    }

    /**
     * Makes the close button at the specified indes visible or invisible
     */
    public void setCloseButtonVisibleAt(int aIndex, boolean aVisible) {
        CloseButtonTab cbt = (CloseButtonTab) getTabComponentAt(aIndex);
        cbt.closingLabel.setVisible(aVisible);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component, String tip, int index) {
        super.insertTab(title, icon, component, tip, index);
        setTabComponentAt(index, new CloseButtonTab(component, title, icon));
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitleAt(int index, String title) {
        super.setTitleAt(index, title);
        CloseButtonTab cbt = (CloseButtonTab) getTabComponentAt(index);
        cbt.label.setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void setIconAt(int index, Icon icon) {
        super.setIconAt(index, icon);
        CloseButtonTab cbt = (CloseButtonTab) getTabComponentAt(index);
        cbt.label.setIcon(icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void setComponentAt(int index, Component component) {
        CloseButtonTab cbt = (CloseButtonTab) getTabComponentAt(index);
        super.setComponentAt(index, component);
        cbt.tab = component;
    }

    //note: setToolTipTextAt(int) must NOT be overridden !

    private Icon getImageIcon(String aImageName) {
        URL imageUrl = CloseableTabbedPane.class.getClassLoader().getResource(aImageName);
        if (imageUrl == null) {
            return new PaintedCrossIcon();
        }
        ImageIcon result = new ImageIcon(imageUrl);
        if (result.getIconWidth() != -1) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class CloseButtonTab extends JPanel {
        private Component tab;
        private JLabel label;
        private JLabel closingLabel;

        public CloseButtonTab(Component aTab, String aTitle, Icon aIcon) {
            tab = aTab;
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setVisible(true);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);

            label = new JLabel(aTitle);
            label.setIcon(aIcon);
            add(label, gbc);
            if (CLOSING_ICON == null) {
                CLOSING_ICON = getImageIcon(iconFileName);
                CLOSING_ICON_SELECTED = getImageIcon(selectedIconFileName);
            }
            closingLabel = new JLabel(CLOSING_ICON);
            closingLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) getParent().getParent();
                    int tabIndex = indexOfComponent(tab);
                    if (tabClosingListener != null) {
                        if (tabClosingListener.selectTabBeforeClosing(tabIndex)) {
                            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
                        }
                        if (tabClosingListener.tabClosing(tabIndex)) {
                            tabbedPane.removeTabAt(tabIndex);
                        }
                    } else {
                        tabbedPane.removeTabAt(tabIndex);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (CLOSING_ICON_SELECTED != null) {
                        closingLabel.setIcon(CLOSING_ICON_SELECTED);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (CLOSING_ICON_SELECTED != null) {
                        closingLabel.setIcon(CLOSING_ICON);
                    }
                }
            });
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            add(closingLabel, gbc);
        }
    }

    static int count = 0;

    /**
     * For testing purposes.
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new CloseableTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("test" + count, new JPanel());
        count++;
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add tab");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tabbedPane.addTab("test" + count, new JPanel());
                count++;
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700,  400);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What L&F causes this?

Comment: I think the problem is that the CloseButtonTab (a JPanel) isn't stretching horizontally to fit the visual width of the tab. Change the background color of it to see what I mean. So, any tricks to push the closingLabel out to the right (by adding a `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` just before it, perhaps) won't work by itself. You probably also have to tinker with the TabbedPaneUI to tell it to fill the tab horizontally with the panel that you provide it.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is caused by the fact that `JTabbedPane` doesn't use the whole area for the tab component. If you draw e.g. a red border around your `CloseButtonTab` you can see that it does not occupy the space that is available for the tab and thus even an alignment using `GridBagConstraints.EAST` doesn't work (because there is no space). I have no idea how to tell `JTabbedPane` to make the tab component "fill" the available space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation using `JLayer`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class CloseableTabbedPaneTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets(2, 2, 2, 50));
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("bbbbbbbb", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("ccc", new JPanel());

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JLayer<JTabbedPane>(tabbedPane, new CloseableTabbedPaneLayerUI()));
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("add tab") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tabbedPane.addTab("test", new JPanel());
      }
    }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new CloseableTabbedPaneTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class CloseableTabbedPaneLayerUI extends LayerUI<JTabbedPane> {
  private final JPanel p = new JPanel();
  private final Point pt = new Point(-100, -100);
  private final JButton button = new JButton("x") {
    @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(16, 16);
    }
  };
  public CloseableTabbedPaneLayerUI() {
    super();
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setRolloverEnabled(false);
  }
  @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    super.paint(g, c);
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      JLayer jlayer = (JLayer) c;
      JTabbedPane tabPane = (JTabbedPane) jlayer.getView();
      for (int i = 0; i < tabPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
        Rectangle rect = tabPane.getBoundsAt(i);
        Dimension d = button.getPreferredSize();
        int x = rect.x + rect.width - d.width - 2;
        int y = rect.y + (rect.height - d.height) / 2;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, d.width, d.height);
        button.setForeground(r.contains(pt) ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
        SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, button, p, r);
      }
    }
  }
  @Override public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    ((JLayer)c).setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
  }
  @Override public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    ((JLayer)c).setLayerEventMask(0);
    super.uninstallUI(c);
  }
  @Override protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JTabbedPane> l) {
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
      pt.setLocation(e.getPoint());
      JTabbedPane tabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) l.getView();
      int index = tabbedPane.indexAtLocation(pt.x, pt.y);
      if (index >= 0) {
        Rectangle rect = tabbedPane.getBoundsAt(index);
        Dimension d = button.getPreferredSize();
        int x = rect.x + rect.width - d.width - 2;
        int y = rect.y + (rect.height - d.height) / 2;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, d.width, d.height);
        if (r.contains(pt)) {
          tabbedPane.removeTabAt(index);
        }
      }
      l.getView().repaint();
    }
  }
  @Override protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JTabbedPane> l) {
    pt.setLocation(e.getPoint());
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) l.getView();
    int index = tabbedPane.indexAtLocation(pt.x, pt.y);
    if (index >= 0) {
      tabbedPane.repaint(tabbedPane.getBoundsAt(index));
    } else {
      tabbedPane.repaint();
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit:

Here is an example using a `GlassPane`(Note: this is NOT tested at all):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CloseableTabbedPaneTest2 {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets(2, 2, 2, 50));
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("bbbbbbbb", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("ccc", new JPanel());

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 10));
    p.add(tabbedPane);
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("add tab") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tabbedPane.addTab("test", new JScrollPane(new JTree()));
      }
    }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        JPanel gp = new CloseableTabbedPaneGlassPane(tabbedPane);
        tabbedPane.getRootPane().setGlassPane(gp);
        gp.setOpaque(false);
        gp.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new CloseableTabbedPaneTest2().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class CloseableTabbedPaneGlassPane extends JPanel {
  private final Point pt = new Point(-100, -100);
  private final JButton button = new JButton("x") {
    @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(16, 16);
    }
  };
  private final JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
  private final Rectangle buttonRect = new Rectangle(button.getPreferredSize());

  public CloseableTabbedPaneGlassPane(JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {
    super();
    this.tabbedPane = tabbedPane;
    MouseAdapter h = new Handler();
    tabbedPane.addMouseListener(h);
    tabbedPane.addMouseMotionListener(h);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setRolloverEnabled(false);
  }
  @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Point glassPt = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(tabbedPane, 0, 0, this);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
      Rectangle tabRect = tabbedPane.getBoundsAt(i);
      int x = tabRect.x + tabRect.width - buttonRect.width - 2;
      int y = tabRect.y + (tabRect.height - buttonRect.height) / 2;
      buttonRect.setLocation(x, y);
      button.setForeground(buttonRect.contains(pt) ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
      buttonRect.translate(glassPt.x, glassPt.y);
      SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, button, this, buttonRect);
    }
  }
  class Handler extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      pt.setLocation(e.getPoint());
      int index = tabbedPane.indexAtLocation(pt.x, pt.y);
      if (index >= 0) {
        Rectangle tabRect = tabbedPane.getBoundsAt(index);
        int x = tabRect.x + tabRect.width - buttonRect.width - 2;
        int y = tabRect.y + (tabRect.height - buttonRect.height) / 2;
        buttonRect.setLocation(x, y);
        if (buttonRect.contains(pt)) {
          tabbedPane.removeTabAt(index);
        }
      }
      tabbedPane.repaint();
    }
    @Override public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
      pt.setLocation(e.getPoint());
      int index = tabbedPane.indexAtLocation(pt.x, pt.y);
      if (index >= 0) {
        tabbedPane.repaint(tabbedPane.getBoundsAt(index));
      } else {
        tabbedPane.repaint();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried the code but from the screenshot it seems to do what I wanted. However, as much as I would like to say that this answer helped me, I can't because I'm forced to use Java 6 in our project (due to our customers and the applications servers they use) and JLayer is since Java 7. Please, can anyone find a solution also for Java 6? thx

Comment: @user3514427 by using JXLayer (more in Official Oracle tutorial), or by override own BasicTabbedPaneUI (I'm sure a few good code here)

Comment: Wow, the second solution using setGlassPane() actually works! (even on Java 6). Cool. but I still wish there was an easier solution based on using setTabComponentAt(..) and some layouting trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TabComponentsDemoProject/src/components/ButtonTabComponent.java

The close button is painted by this itself so if can be placed anywhere.

Comment: I have already tris this class and it suffers from the very same problem!

`final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("test" + count, new JPanel());
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(count, new ButtonTabComponent(tabbedPane));`