# Eclipse style JTabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have seen the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054466/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-jtabbedpane-tab,)

However , I have worked on a even harder project, I want to customize the Jtabbedpane as [this](http://www.eclipse.org/screenshots/images/SDK-RedFlag_Linux.png)

please watch the component which like a JTabbedPane.

as you can see, there are many tags and two buttons used to minimize and maxumize on the tab title. More additon when there are too many tabs there will be anothoer button and you can click it to get those tags that you can not see.

I have no idea about How to achieve this, please Help me.

Comment: I don't know if you're aware of it. Eclipse is not based on Swing, it uses its own toolkit called SWT. Means, these guys achieved what you see not by using Swing but by using SWT.

Answer (score 1):

To start, you could try [*Tabs With Custom Components*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html). Like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638963/261156), it uses `setTabComponentAt()` to add a custom `ButtonTabComponent` that has a checkbox.