# How can I use tabInsets when using getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()?

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, uimanager

I need to set UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()) to make the button size just around its name, but when I do this UIManager.put("TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets(2, 2, 2, 50)) has no longer effect, making the CloseableTabbedPaneLayerUI class ([Closeable JTabbedPane - alignment of the close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634047/closeable-jtabbedpane-alignment-of-the-close-button/24638963#24638963)) to display the close button over the tab name.